# C# project involving Asynchronous Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I was wondering what would be good application (server&client) to build using Asynchronous sockets?

Something other than chat or file transfer.

Answer (score 0):

A multiplayer game is always fun to make. *Any* client-server application can be made using asynchronous sockets though, in fact under the hood there is no difference in the type of socket used for both asynchronous and synchronous, it's just a different way .NET has implemented the classes around them.

Comment: I wouldn't mind making some small multilayer game but I am still studying XNA

Comment: Just like a chat application, people like to try out a game a few times, even if it's tic-tac-toe or something else that doesn't use graphics. If practicing the use of sockets is what you want, you don't have to spend too much time on making things pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Big file transfer. Create a robust solution to transfer >1GB files over a network.

Keep the total amount of memory used low.
Keep the total transfer speed close to theoretical speed limits.

Enjoy some great programming problems.

Now do the same with really small files and try to get close to theoretical speed limits.

Now use this code to create automatic testing of the sockets.

After doing this you should be a fluent socket programmer.

Answer (score 0):

A program which shows the quality of a network connection